# How to get data field dyanmic data from the jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Dynamic option i have :

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label">tag:</label>
        <select class="form-control"  id="called_id">
       <option>Select </option>
      @foreach($news['data'] as $j_d) 
      <option data-get="{{$new->id}}" value="<?php echo $j_d->id; ?>" <?php echo $j_d->title_eng; ?></option>
       @endforeach 
       </select>
      </div>
```

> Jquery code from where i am getting the value of option data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calling_id').on('change',function(){
   var data=$(this).val();
    var id = $(this).data('called_data');


  })
})
</script>
```

But M not able to get the data value in jquery what is the reason m not able to understand.. can anyone pls help

Result in console:

data value Undefined and id value 2 correct.

Comment: everything working fine but i am not gettint data-worker value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the selected `option` within the dropdown since `this` refers to the `select` tag and which doesn't have any data attribute.

```
var id = $('option:selected', this).data('worker');
// or
var id = $(this).find('option:selected').data('worker');
```

Comment: @Pooja : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try getting it through the selected option of the select :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#news').on('change',function(){
   var data=$(this).val();
    var idss = $(this).find(':selected').data('news');
    console.log(idss,data);

  })
})
```

Because you are setting data value for the option and not the select itself.

Hope this helps!